# Which component of the FURPS model refers to ease of serviving in FURPS model?

Tags: requirements, furps+

I am engaged into a discussion with my peers where there is a disagreement between where ease of service fits into [FURPS model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FURPS).

I feel it should be part of **Usability**. Though my peers suggest it should be under **Supportability**

Would appreciate it if someone can clarify the confusion.

Comment: "ease of service" is not something I'm familiar with, perhaps you could define it. And, btw, have you checked that it means the same thing to you as your colleagues?

Comment: @NathanCooper As per the wikipedia link for FURPS, it mentions `Serviceability` under the heading Supportability. Though I feel since it's ease of use so maybe that has to do more with UX which comes under `Usability`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have to be one or the other.

The purpose of FURPS(+) is to help categorize requirements to make sure all of the different aspects of a system are covered. By looking at the requirements, a team can check to make sure that all of the topics are covered. If one is missing, this can be raised as a risk or some time can be spent to elicit the appropriate requirements from the stakeholders.

A requirement may not fall cleanly into one category.

One example is that requirements about where the system can be installed appear to fall under Supportability. However, there is probably some kind of installation and configuration documentation to help the person who installs the system. This could be in the form of a printed manual, an electronic help file, or an on-screen wizard. Documentation falls under Usability, even if that documentation is related to installing and configuring the system. If I was going to be tagging each requirement, I'd tag an installation documentation requirement as both usability and supportability (perhaps considering more granular tags, like documentation, configurability, and installability).

Similarly, I can see requirements associated with Functionality (especially Security) also being closely related to Reliability (considering Availability, Stability, and Accuracy). Security requirements often consider these factors.

Trying to put requirements into a singular bucket does not appear to be the intent of FURPS. Instead, use FURPS to understand what topics you should be discussing with stakeholders and where there may be gaps. It would be quite unusual for stakeholders not to have needs or expectations in each of these categories, so not understanding those needs or expectations would be a risk for the project. A structured ways to find gaps can help the team mitigate that risk.